# How to mock IDbSet with Rhino Mocks

Tags: c#, entity-framework, rhino-mocks

I can't get this working at all. I've got this code in my test:

```
MockRepository repository = new MockRepository();
IDbSet<SystemUser> userSet = repository.StrictMock<IDbSet<SystemUser>>();
Expect.Call(userSet.Any(u => u.Id == "UserName")).Return(true);
// More code follows
```

But it bombs out on the `StrictMock` line with the error:

> System.TypeLoadException: Method 'Create' on type
>   'IDbSet`1Proxy1862178487664986a7bd03ad3b5c6f2c' from assembly
>   'DynamicProxyGenAssembly2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=a621a9e7e5c32e69' tried to implicitly implement an
>   interface method with weaker type parameter constraints

Any ideas what this could be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have encountered a known issue that Rhino.Mocks (version 3.6.0.0) has with generic method constraints.

The 'Create' method:

```
TDerivedEntity Create<TDerivedEntity>() where TDerivedEntity : class, TEntity
```

is failing to be generated correctly because of the constraints `where TDerivedEntity : class, TEntity`.

There is more information regarding the bug here : [Can't get RhinoMocks to emit a mock that follows the generic type restriction rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382624/cant-get-rhinomocks-to-emit-a-mock-that-follows-the-generic-type-restriction-rul)

Unfortunately, it looks like we are going to have to wait for the next version of Rhino.Mocks to address the issue.

Comment: Ah, thats not ideal... I've created my own manual mock now anyway. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

For those who are still looking for a solution for this problem. rhino mocks 3.6.1 and later solves this issue.